# MS teams bot - create new conversation

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using the botbuilder-python to build MS Teams bot.
Following samples I am able to respond to messages. What I'm struggling with is creating completely new message, without existing activity passed from Teams. I modified some code from the tests (https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/62b0512a4dd918fa0d3837207012b31213aaedcc/libraries/botframework-connector/tests/test_conversations.py) but I'm getting:

botbuilder.schema.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException: (BadSyntax) Could not parse tenant id

What is it, where can I find it (I can fish it out from request but it's not ideal) and how do I pass it? Can anyone point me at any Python samples of creating a new conversation?

Comment: are you trying to do something like Welcome messages?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. I'm integrating client's application with Teams, it needs to send notifications to users at a specific time to nudge them to do something.

Comment: Could you please post this query directly on [Python SDK Issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/issues)? We had [C# & Node.JS code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#net-example-from-this-samplehttpsgithubcomofficedevmicrosoft-teams-sample-complete-csharpblob32c39268d60078ef54f21fb3c6f42d122b97da22template-bot-master-csharpsrcdialogsexamplesteamsproactivemsgto1to1dialogcs) where you could specify tenantId in the conversation parameters but don't have Python sample for this.

Comment: I would recommend starting with the [Python EchoBot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/master/samples/EchoBot-with-State/main.py) and working from there. It should give you the framework to start developing your bot.

Comment: @tdurnford as mentioned in my question, all the samples only respond to messages using request from Teams and I was able to do that. What I'm trying to do is create a completely new conversation, without an existing activity passed from Teams.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT - I'll do that but it felt like it's a question about usage, not an actual issue

Comment: The bot framework requires users to message the bot before the bot is able to message users to prevent spam bots. You can send welcome messages to the user when they join the conversation, but in the Teams channel the user still has to message the bot before the bot can send a welcome message. You can possibly look into [proactive messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/16fb81ffdf84fa022ca86d0caede9c1f80509940/libraries/botbuilder-core/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py#L35), but you would need to have a conversation reference which typically comes from an activity.

Comment: @tdurnford Thanks! That pretty much answers my question. Is there any other way to send any type of notifications to specific users in Teams? Or is it possible for an organisation to allow bot to initiate conversations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, just in case anybody else is trying to do the same thing and gets stuck:

```
to = ChannelAccount(id=to_user_id)

bot_channel = ChannelAccount(id=bot_id)
activity_reply = Activity(type=ActivityTypes.message, channel_id='msteams',from_property=bot_channel,recipient=to,text=message)

credentials=MicrosoftAppCredentials(app_id, app_password)
JwtTokenValidation.authenticate_request(activity_reply, "Authorization", credentials)
# That's where you pass the tenant id
reply_conversation_params=ConversationParameters(bot=bot_channel, members=[to], activity=activity_reply, channel_data={ 'tenant': { 'id': tenant_id } })
connector = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url='https://smba.trafficmanager.net/uk/')

# Create conversation
conversation = connector.conversations.create_conversation(reply_conversation_params)
# And send it
connector.conversations.send_to_conversation(conversation.id, activity_reply)
```

Comment: How do you pre-determine what the bot and user ids should be? Both have prefixes from what I see as well (e.g. 28: 29:)

Comment: I tried the above code using values found in turn_context.activity and got botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: (BadArgument) User is from different region.   If these values are from teams and don't work where do I find the right ones?

Comment: It's failing with "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" for me. Not sure about the "to_user_id", where it comes from. Any idea?